How to place CROSS APPLY inside an In-Line Table-valued Functions in T-SQL
I have a table Source that contains a column tags that has a string data type.
Here is an example of a row from the column:
["tag_a", "tag_b", "tag_c", "tag_d"]
The following code extracts each tag and creates a new column through a cross apply with the original tag list.
SELECT
DISTINCT tags as TAGS_LIST,
TRIM(' "[]' from value) as TAG
FROM
DB.dbo.Source
CROSS APPLY
STRING_SPLIT(tags, ',');

The previous example would yield the following table:



TAGS_LIST
TAG




["tag_a", "tag_b", "tag_c", "tag_d"]
tag_a


["tag_a", "tag_b", "tag_c", "tag_d"]
tag_b


["tag_a", "tag_b", "tag_c", "tag_d"]
tag_c


["tag_a", "tag_b", "tag_c", "tag_d"]
tag_d



It works fine on its own.
However, I am unable to fit it into a  In-Line Table-valued Function:
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTAGS](@STARTDATE DATETIME, @ENDDATE DATETIME) 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
RETURN
    (
SELECT
DISTINCT tags as TAGS_LIST,
TRIM(' "[]' from value) as TAG
FROM
DB.dbo.Source
WHERE
DB.dbo.Source.[creation_date] >= @STARTDATE AND
DB.dbo.Source.[creation_date] <= @ENDDATE
CROSS APPLY
STRING_SPLIT(tags, ',')
    );

This gives me the following error:

Incorrect syntax: 'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the only statement in the batch.

Placing it before WHERE also doesn't work.
I could not find any specification telling me CROSS APPLY could not be placed inside a In-Line Table-valued Function.
How can I have the CROSS APPLY inside of a In-Line Table-valued Function?
I have tried positioning the cross apply in different places of the functions.
I have tried researching on CROSS APPLY inside of a In-Line Table-valued Function, but have only found articles that talk about them as separate.
The answers to "How to split array in json using json_query" does not answer this question, as that thread has nothing to do with CROSS APPLY inside of In-Line Table-valued Functions.

Cross Apply is a kind of join. It belongs in the From clause. It’s supposed to contain a full query in between the parens. Also you must give an alias for its joined result by adding as MyCoolStuff after the parens.

Your "tags" looks suspiciously similar to JSON, why not use proper json methods instead of rolling your own?

That's not a multi-statement TVF, it's an inline -TVF.

Also don't quote your code please - use code formatting

It's valid JSON, you should just do CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Tags) AS j(value)

Thank you, @Charlieface , your comment was very helpful.
I was able to re-format the function, removing the WITH and employing the proper OPENJSON in place of SPLIT_STRING.

Did you miss my comment above? This is not a multi-statement TVF

APPLY operations happen at the same level as JOINs, in between the FROM and the WHERE clauses.

Found a solution.
I moved the CROSS APPLY to a subquery:
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTAGS](@STARTDATE DATETIME, @ENDDATE DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH T AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT tags as TAGS_LIST, TRIM(' "[]' from value) as TAG
        FROM DB.dbo.Source
        CROSS APPLY
           STRING_SPLIT(tags, ',')
    )
    SELECT T.TAGS_LIST AS TAGS_LIST, T.TAG AS TAG
    FROM T, DB.dbo.Source
    WHERE
        DB.dbo.Source.[creation_date] >= @STARTDATE AND
        DB.dbo.Source.[creation_date] <= @ENDDATE
);


That's a very poor JSON parser. What happens if there is a , inside one of the strings?

In your final SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE, the FROM has 2 tables but the 2nd one (DB.dbo.Source) does not appear in the SELECT, and there is also no JOIN on it, so why is it in the FROM? I think it can be removed, along with the WHERE part that refers to it. The WHERE might need to be moved to inside the WITH part, after the CROSS APPLY, and then you could perhaps also eliminate the WITH part.

@PeterB Thank you for your comment. I have moved the where inside the WITH clause and omitted the second table from the final FROM.
Removing the WITH, however, raises the error presented in the original question.

@Charlieface Thank you for your concern.
The tags in the original dataset cannot have commas in them, so it is not an issue in this particular instance.

I think @PeterB intends something like this RETURN SELECT s.tags AS TAGS_LIST, TRIM(' "[]' FROM sp.value) AS TAG FROM dbo.Source s CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(s.tags, ',') WHERE s.creation_date >= @STARTDATE ANDs.creation_date <= @ENDDATE so there is no need for the WITH or the double join.
